# Neural Nework code or library for MSP430G2553 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, electronics, machine-learning, embedded-systems

I am new here and i am new to neural network also. :P
I have gone through the concepts of Neural Networks but i want to implement it in my project including microcontroller **MSP430G2553** on *LaunchPad* Series.
I am using some sensors and i want to use some neural network code to manipulate the data from sensors to get some threshold.
I went through this [post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/568/is-it-possible-to-run-a-neural-network-on-a-microcontroller) and tried to implement the codes from the link given but it is giving some error on less ram, i guess it is due to my mcu.

So, i wanted some help regarding the neural network code or library for *Energia* which i should use.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it is a good idea to include details of what what you would like to achieve, what you have tried, what you expected to see & what you actually saw. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

[One page linked](http://robotics.hobbizine.com/arduinoann.html) says the algorithm is fine for the ATmega328's 2KB of SRAM, [another](http://diydrones.com/group/arducopter-evolution-team/forum/topics/neuroduino-a-neural-network-library-for-arduino) is for the ATmega2560's 8KB of SRAM.

Your [MSP430G2553](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430G2553) has 0.5KB of RAM, so I think that's the primary reason you can't get it to run on that controller.

There are other microcontrollers in the MSP430 line that have more memory - if you [look at the other LaunchPads](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-msp.html#tabs) you can see that you've got the one with the smallest RAM available in a LaunchPad - others have up to [64KB](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-msp430-msp-exp432p401r.html#tabs).